# Pass data to modal and show table of results

Tags: php, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a button on a page that has a data ID associated with it to pass the feedbackID of the record. When the button is clicked, I need a modal to open up and display the results of a recordset. It is not opening the modal currently. If I run the show_gess_responses.php the results show correctly. Any help is appreciated. Here is the code of the page:

```
<button name="view" value="view" id="<?php echo($gess_feedback->getColumnVal("feedbackID")); ?>" class="btn btn-sm mb-2 btn-info view_data">View Responses</button>

<div id="dataModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Here is the log of responses regarding this submission:</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body" id="response_details">  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div> 

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.view_data').click(function(){  
     // gather your inputs 
      var url="show_gess_responses.php";
      $.ajax({
        url: url, // your back-end PHP script, will return the HTML needed
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
           feedbackID2: $(this).attr("id"),
        },
        success: function(result){
           $('#response_details').html(result)         
           $('#dataModal').modal('show');
        }
     })
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>
```

Here is the show_gess_responses.php code:

```
<?php
$gess_feedback_responses = new WA_MySQLi_RS("gess_feedback_responses",$sdpc_i,0);
$gess_feedback_responses->setQuery("SELECT * from gess_feedback_response where feedbackID = ?");
$gess_feedback_responses->bindParam("i", "".$_GET['feedbackID2']  ."", "-1"); //colname
$gess_feedback_responses->execute();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jq-3.3.1/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.24/b-1.7.0/b-colvis-1.7.0/b-html5-1.7.0/b-print-1.7.0/r-2.2.7/sc-2.0.3/sb-1.0.1/datatables.min.css"/> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jq-3.3.1/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.24/b-1.7.0/b-colvis-1.7.0/b-html5-1.7.0/b-print-1.7.0/r-2.2.7/sc-2.0.3/sb-1.0.1/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" class="init">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 0 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            }
        ],
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
    } );
} 
);
    </script>
<style type="text/css">
td img {margin: 0;}
table.sortable th:not(.sorttable_sorted):not(.sorttable_sorted_reverse):not(.sorttable_nosort):after { 
    content: " \25B4\25BE" 
}
table.sortable tbody tr:nth-child(2n) td {
  background: #cccccc;
}
table.sortable tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1) td {
  background: #ccfffff;
}
</style>
   
</head>
            <table id="example" class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        
        <th align="left" valign="top"><strong><font size="-1">Date Submitted</font></strong></th>
        <th align="left" valign="top"><strong><font size="-1">Date Submitted</font></strong></th>
         <th align="left" valign="top"><strong><font size="-1">Name</font></strong></th>
          <th align="left" valign="top"><strong><font size="-1">Response</font></strong></th></tr>

      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
$wa_startindex = 0;
while(!$gess_feedback_responses->atEnd()) {
  $wa_startindex = $gess_feedback_responses->Index;
?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo($gess_feedback_responses->getColumnVal("date_submitted")); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($gess_feedback_responses->getColumnVal("date_submitted"))); ?></td>
     <td></td>
     <td><?php echo($gess_feedback_responses->getColumnVal("response")); ?></td>
     
     </tr>
     <?php
  $gess_feedback_responses->moveNext();
}
$gess_feedback_responses->moveFirst(); //return RS to first record
unset($wa_startindex);
unset($wa_repeatcount);
?></tbody></table>
```

Comment: What library are you using for `$.modal()`?

Comment: Maybe try Fancybox, it can also do ajax requests for you.

Comment: I am using bootstrap modal.